# Why group is primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, substitution

Transitive substitution group $G$ of degree $n$ contain the substitution $g$, represented as the product of two independent cycles of lengths $n_1$, $n_2$, where $n_1+n_2=n$ and $(n_1 , n_2)=1$. Why $G$ should be primitive.
I think the criterion of primitiveness will do. So it must be shown that there is no subgroup between the stabilizer of any element and the group ($G$ is primitive $\Leftrightarrow \nexists H\lt G:G_\alpha \lt H \lt G$ and $G\neq H \neq G_\alpha$ )

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

There is a transitive imprimitive subgroup of $S_6$ that contains the permutation $(1,3,2,4)(5,6)$ and preserves the blocks system $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5,6\}\}$.

Comment: Well, what if we add the condition of mutual simplicity of n1 and n2?

Comment: If the group if imprimitive, then $n_1$ and $n_2$ are both divisible by the size of the blocks, so the claim is true if $\gcd(n_1,n_2)=1$.